# Perl Module Archive::Zip - How do I know whether a Member is a Directory of File?

Tags: perl, perl-module

A quick question with `Archive::Zip`. How do I know whether a member is a directory or file? I need to move all Ear files in a particular Zip to another directory. However, some directories also have the `.ear` suffix, and I don't want those.

I'm doing:

```
my @jarMembers = $zip->membersMatching('^.*\.jar');
foreach my $member (@jarMembers) {
    my $fileName = basename($member->FileName());
    $zip->ExtractMember($member, "$zipRootDir/$fileName";
}
```

And I want to verify I won't be getting the directory `foo.ear`.

I suspect that directory names are suppose to end in a slash, but there's nothing in the documentation that explicitly states that. I also notice special Archive::Zip::FileMember methods, but not much in the way of documentation in accessing them. Is it simply something like this?

```
if ($member->externalFileName()) {
   print "Member is a file\n";
} else {
   print "Member is a directory\n";
}
```

Will that tell me whether or not a member is a file or a directory, or is my first code snippet sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version of Perl (5.10.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.5) has this method in `Archive::Zip::Member`:

> ```
>  isDirectory()
>      Returns true if I am a directory.
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't see this in the Archive::Zip documentation.